# SQL Server exception combination primary key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert into a SQL Server database. I have a table with four columns and the primary key is a combination of three columns `<name, coursename, semester>`.

I am trying to insert a record in this table and I want the program to give me an error when I insert a duplicate. However when I insert although the record is not inserted, no error is issued.

Can someone tell me the problem with my code? Thank you

Here is part of my code:

```
try
{
    string semester1 = semester.Text + syear.Text + "-" + eyear.Text;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SOURAYA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=transcripts;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("insert into courses(name, coursename, semester, grade) values('" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + course_name.Text + "','" + semester1 + "',"+grades.Text+"')", conn);

    conn.Open();
    command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException s)
{
    if (s.Number == 2627)
    {
        error.Text = "Record already exists";
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: what marc_s said, and: the text of your error is only set when `s.Number` equals 2627, in every other case of an `SqlException`, nothing happens.

Comment: how do i handle all the cases?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're either missing a single quote or you have an extra one depending on grade column type. Using parameters as @marc_s said will also solve this.
2. To handle other cases you can add a generic handler, something like this:

   else { error.Text = "Unexpected error no: " + s.Number; }